# Use Schur complement to show that $ 1^TD1 \ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, schur-complement

I'm trying to prove following statement:

> Suppose $ D \preceq 0$ on the subspace $\{z: 1^Tz=0\}$. Use Schur complement to show that $1^TD1\ge0$.

I've done something like this

> $1^TD1\ge0 \Leftrightarrow\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1^T \\ 1 & -D \end{matrix}\right)  \succeq 0$

But I don't know what to do next. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: what is $e$ in this formulation?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I've corrected it

Comment: @percusse $e$ means the all-one vector. It's OK to change it to $\mathbf1$, but $e$ is actually more popular than $\mathbf1$ in linear algebra literature.

Comment: @TatianaJašurková Are you sure that your question is correct? If $D=-I$, then $z^TDz<0$ for **every** $z$, including those orthogonal to $1$ and also $1$ itself.

Comment: Well, that's all I've got... Actually I need to prove this according to much bigger statement that: if  D holds that $ z^TDz<=0$ for all $z: 1^Tz=0$ then there exist vector $w>=0$ such that $G= w1^T +1w^T-\frac{1}{2}D \succeq 0$

Comment: As no one has answered your question yet, you may change the problem statement to that "bigger statement", if the latter is where your question originates. The current statement is wrong, but your "bigger statement" is correct.

Comment: @user1551 In linear algebra e usually means a column of the identity matrix.

Comment: @percusse I'm talking about journal papers. The $j$-th column of the identity matrix is denoted by $e_j$, but $e$ without subscript means $\mathbf1$. My impression is that unlike $e$, the notation $\mathbf1$ is more prevalent in statistics or engineering journals, but relatively rare in linear algebra journals such as in LAA or LAMA.

Comment: @user1551 Not according to my experience with those journals to be honest. But anyways tomato, tomato as long as you define it somewhere.